# Difference between NSView and NSViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, osx-lion

What's the difference between NSView and NSViewController is XCode 4 Cocoa application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSView is just the view in MVC. NSViewController has a NSView (or a subclass of NSView), and also contains the code for the controller in the MVC model.

I may be wrong, since I'm drawing the answer from my experience with iOS, but I think it should be about the same for OSX.

Comment: Is it ok to not use the NSViewController in the app?

Comment: @Kir: Using the NSViewController is one (good) way to organize the code that is related to the view that it is in charge of. I think it is possible not to use it, but is there any advantage by doing that?

Comment: If you're not using it, you have to write your own controller code and connect it to the view from scratch. This is some common task and NSViewController exists to give you a solid starting point to further customize in order to make it fit your needs.